# R Shiny select input unselected

Tags: r, shiny

Hello How can i get info that Select input is still unselected i try something like

```
server.R
output$Country<-renderUI({selectInput(inputId ="inputCountry",label ="change options",choices=data$Country) })

if(input$inputCountry=="")
```

or

```
if(is.null(input$inputCountry))
```

Answer (score 0):

is.null should do it (depending on quite how you initialise the input)

Answer (score 0):

As doctorG said, `is.null` is the correct choice if you want to check whether an input variable has already been "activated". There is however a better option in case you want to perform this check in a reactive environment, which is

```
req(input$inputCountry)
```

This will automatically stop the current `observe` or `renderXXX` function if the `input` is either `""`, `NULL` or `FALSE`. `req` can also be used inline in the following manner

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({hist(rnorm(req(input$n)))})
```

The `req` function also has an optional argument `cancelOutput` which can be quite handy in certain usecases. See `?req`.